# ModuleNotFoundError but Installed, python not recognized

Tags: anaconda, miniconda

In `Miniconda 3` I installed `matplotlib` packages but get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'` when executing script.

I don't know what changed, everything worked fine for weeks and then I got error messages regarding `ModuleNotFoundError` for `pscopg2` and others.  Therefore, I don't believe `matplotlib` is the problem, I want to understand how to correct this and avoid it in the future.

Here's what I see:

[image]

Based on other answers I tried the following:

- Added the first PATH variable seen in the pic:
  [image]
- Uninstalled and reinstalled `Miniconda` with a reboot after the uninstall, then recreated the virtual environment.
- Printed out the following `sys` info:

`sys.excecutable`:`C:\Users\Drew\miniconda3\python.exe`

`sys.path`: `['E:\\Minitab_Killer', 'C:\\Users\\Drew\\miniconda3\\python311.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Drew\\miniconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Drew\\miniconda3\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\Drew\\miniconda3', 'C:\\Users\\Drew\\miniconda3\\Lib\\site-packages']`

I don't understand how this information is actionable/changeable.

What's even more confusing to me is now `Visual Studio Code` doesn't even recognize `Python`, let alone the module:

[image]

What should I try next?